# Динамическое подключение модулей в проект C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, модули

Есть приложение C# MVC. Оно используется у нескольких заказчиков с разным набором функционала. Сейчас это реализовано следующим образом: копируется проект одного заказчика, в него допиливается новый / удаляется ненужный функционал. С увеличением заказчиков такая схема становится очень неудобной в поддержке. Необходимо в новой реализации данного приложения сделать один проект-каркас, а различный функционал подключать в виде отдельных внешних модулей. Что можно посмотреть/почитать, чтобы реализовать данную идею?

Answer (score 6):

Для создания расширяемых приложений в .NET включен MEF (Managed Extensibility Framework) и MAF (Managed Add-in Framework) -- можно использовать в любых типах приложений, включая MVC.
Введение в MEF есть на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx).
Использование MEF с шаблоном MVC также есть на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh708870(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Прочитайте про архитектурные паттерны: `DDD` и `SOA`, а еще лучше наймите грамотного архитектора, т.к. нельзя просто так взять, прочитать книжечку и сразу спроектировать грамотную архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону **Onion/Clean Architecture**, попробуйте писать **адаптивный код, используйте абстракции** там где они нужны ...